# How to evaluate a script in Chrome headless?

Tags: google-chrome

Node has `-e` and `-p` flags for evaluate and evaluate-and-print respectively. I know there is a `--repl` flag for Chrome headless, but I wonder is there a way to evaluate-and-print an expression as well, e.g:

```
$ chrome --headless --eval-and-print 'navigator.hardwareConcurrency'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it accepts to read from stdin, so this awful hack "works":

```
$ echo -e 'navigator.hardwareConcurrency\nquit\n' | chrome --headless --repl
[0412/235456.154837:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(980)] Lost UI shared context.
[0412/235456.214132:INFO:headless_shell.cc(370)] Type a Javascript expression to evaluate or "quit" to exit.
>>> {"result":{"description":"8","type":"number","value":8}}
>>>
```

So, with more awful hacks and `jq`:

```
$ echo -e 'navigator.hardwareConcurrency\nquit\n' | chrome --headless --repl 2>&1 | grep '^>>> {"result":' | cut -c4- | jq -r .result.description
8
```

Answer (score 2):

The headless mode currently only supports:

- printing/screenshots
- dumping the dom
- interaction by repl
- interaction by remote debugger

If you don't want to work with the interactive modes or one of the wrappers around them and don't actually need to navigate to a page then you can use a `data:` url to provide javascript and get the output from `dump-dom`, for example:

`chromium --headless --dump-dom 'data:text/html,<script>document.head.innerHTML="<code>\n"+navigator.hardwareConcurrency+"\n</code>"</script>' | grep -v 'code>'`